# Why ref returns a object contained current key but ref.current returns null?

Tags: reactjs

I declare a ref with useRef and when I console it, shows `{current: div}` but when I console the ref.current it returns undefined

```js
const ref = useRef()

  console.log(ref) // {current: div}
  console.log(ref.current) // undefined
```

Comment: show us snapshot of your code

Comment: Everything related to my question is here

Comment: That's because `console.log` in the devtools shows the current state, not the state when `console.log` was fired.

Comment: Or put another way: when you log an object, the log doesn't evaluate the object immediately, it waits until you click the object in the console. So at the time these lines of code ran, ref.current was undefined, but by the time you clicked the object, ref.current was a div.